# Сумма ячеек таблицы

Tags: php, table

Здравствуйте, есть таблица, в которой генерируются строки, ячейки через foreach:

```html
echo '<table id="rowclick5" class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive-sm">
<tr style="background-color: #f9f9f9;">
  <th><center>Наименование</center></th>
  <th><center>Цена, грн.</center></th>
  <th><center>Гарантия, мес.</center></th>
</tr>';
foreach ($_POST['ch'] as $item) {
  $query = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT * FROM `prices` WHERE `id` = '$item'");
  while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
      echo '<tr>
      <td>'.$result['name'].'</td>
      <td><center>'.$result['price'].'</center></td>
      <td><center>'.$result['warranty'].'</center></td>
  </tr>';
  }
}
echo '</table>';
```

Как мне вывести сумму всех значений с ячеек "Цена" (`.$result['price'].`) посредством PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лично я вижу два возможных варианта.

### Вариант № 1. В лоб.

Посчитать цену в цикле.

```
$price = 0;
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $price += $result['price'];
  echo '<tr>
  <td>'.$result['name'].'</td>
  <td><center>'.$result['price'].'</center></td>
  <td><center>'.$result['warranty'].'</center></td>
  </tr>';
}
```

Но, это далеко не самое лучшее решение.

### Вариант №2. Правильный.

Возложить функцию подсчёта общей суммы на базу данных при помощи агрегатной функции `COUNT`.

```
$priceQuery = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `prices` WHERE `id` = '$item'");
```

Comment: Вариант 2 в цикл надо ставить?

Comment: @АнтонАлександрович, вариант 2 в цикл "ставить" не нужно. Запрос вернёт нужный результат сразу.

Comment: Пишет: Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\osr\OSPanel\domains\site.ua\all\order.php on line 48

Comment: Строка: $priceQuery = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT COUNT(price) FROM `prices` WHERE `id` = '$item'");

Comment: Значит, не правильно получаете результат из скалярного запроса. А, как Вы его получаете пока известно только Вам.